# How do I rearrange (or sort) variables in the VS2010 Watch window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to rearrange variables I've entered into the Watch window, but drag/drop doesn't work, there's no sort on the name column that I can find. Short of deleting and retyping, is there any way to rearrange variables you're watching?

Answer (score 8):

Drag and Drop does work, but what it does is create a copy of the variable at the end of the list.
So the best you can do to arrange the watched variables is to drag the variables one by one in the order that you need and then delete the duplicate ones.

Comment: Drag and drop moves things, clicking copies. So that's not drag and drop, is it?

Comment: Drag and drop must normally move things. But in a watch window it does a copy to end irrespective of where you drag it to.

Comment: It still adds a copy in VS 2015.  Bummer

Comment: It seems to me VS's behaviour is a result of a combination of factors:
(a) the Watch window accepts a text string dragged in from another window
(b) MS never bothered programming it to add it at the exact spot where you dropped it, and so it just adds it at the end
(c) one of these places a text string can be dragged from is the watch window itself
(d) MS never bothered coding any special handling for dragging *within* the watch window.

So I suppose this workaround works, but it's rather annoying if I've a lot of watches and I just want to reorder a few at the beginning!

Comment: There's a request for exactly that in VS's Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/836747/allow-rearranging-of-items-in-the-watch-window.html